# How to fix the camera position relative to the player in Star Wars Jedi: Fallen Order

Tags: star-wars-jedi-fallen-order

I play video games at my PC with mostly mouse and keyboard and use controller only for games that don't require precision (like car games and Fifa). Recently I started to play Star Wars Jedi: Fallen Order and it emphasizes that the controller is the recommended input device to play.

I always enjoyed controlling a 3rd person game with a mouse as it can turn the player AND the camera as well at the same time.

In Fallen Order, to my surprise, I have to use *both joysticks* to control where to look and where to go. That's not very effective, I keep falling down as the camera shows the side of the map while I go forward (and a mouse is 10 times more accurate than a joystick), so I'm looking a way to make the camera be in a fix position above the shoulder of my player (like in Assassin's Creed).

Can I fix the camera position to make it effective?